# How to show result that has been stored in a string variable in a dialog in android

Tags: android, string, qr-code, android-dialog

I am trying to scan QR code with xzing import and show the QR details in the dialog box with 2 buttons.First button should be able to make a call to a fixed number(Emergency Number) and the second button should be able to share QR details along with my current location through whatsapp.

```
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                if (requestCode == 0) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
get the extras that are returned from the intent
                        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");


                        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
    >I want to show the string value in the dialogbox with 2 buttons.                    
                        showDialog(this);

                    }
                }
            }

            private void showDialog(AndroidQrCodeExample androidQrCodeExample) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 >I dont know whether I can use this command setmessage to   display as I am new in android.Please explain me How to do it.                     
.setMessage(contents)
                        .setTitle("Response")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        });

                builder.show();
            }
        }strong text
```

Comment: What is the problem with your existing code for alert?

Comment: The output result from the qr code is being stored in the string variable named contents and i am trying to pass this value to the showdialog method and i am not getting the output but when i tried to write the showdialog method in the onActivityResult function i am getting the result. Can you help me with passing the value from one method to another.

Comment: So you are trying to pass your string back to called activity through onActivityResult  ?

Comment: not exactly.I am trying to pass the string from onActivityResult to showdialog so that the information stored in content should come in dialog.

Comment: So you are getting the string in onActivityResult right?Now you just need to show dialog?

Comment: yeah i want to show dialog with 2 buttons.... first should directly make a call to the mobile number i 'm going to put(just one number) and the other button should share the content on whatsapp.